# Join my select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

My aim is to create a VIEW on properties managed with the branch's town, property details and the number of inspections carried out for these properties. I think I have made the correct SELECT queries, but I am having trouble joining them together.

The tables I am using are

1. YR_property - primary key -  'propertynum' , Foreign Key- branchnum
2. YR_branch - Primary key - branchnum
3. YR_inspection - Primary key 1 - propertynum, Primary key 2 - dateinspected.

This is what I have managed ...

```
SELECT area, city
From YR_branch

SELECT propertynum, COUNT (propertynum)  FROM yr_inspection
GROUP BY propertynum

SELECT propertynum, branchnum, area, city, postcode, prop_type, rooms
FROM YR_property
```

To reiterate, I am trying to join the SELECT statements. Thank you for any help I may receive!

Comment: Have you tried any statements to see if you could get it to work how you want?

Comment: before i put the third table in i tried ... INNER JOIN yr_inspection
ON YR_branch.branchnum = yr_inspection.propertynum;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
select p.propertynum, p.branchnum, p.area, p.city, p.postcode, p.prop_type, p.rooms,
       b.area, b.city, coalesce(i.NumInspected, 0)
from yr_property p join
     yr_branch b
     on p.branchnum = b.branchnum left outer join
     (select propertynum, count(*) as NumInspected
      from yr_inspection i
      group by propertynum
     ) i
     on i.propertynum = p.propertynum;
```

This uses ANSI standard join syntax to bring the tables together.  The inspections table is first aggregated before the join to get the number of inspections on the property.

The `left outer join` ensures that all properties are included, even with no inspections.  The `coalesce()` shows the number of inspections in such a case as 0 rather than NULL.

If you really want a SQL view, then just put `create view <your view name here> as` before the `select`.

Answer (score 1):

The first and the third queries can be merged with a simple JOIN. Then you can merge the third by using subselects. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT propertynum, COUNT (propertynum) 
    FROM yr_inspection GROUP BY propertynum
) a,
(
    SELECT b.area, b.city, p.propertynum, p.branchnum, 
           p.area, p.city, p.postcode, p.prop_type, p.rooms 
    FROM YR_property p, YR_branch b
    WHERE p.branchnum = b.branchnum
) b
where a.propertynum = b.propertynum;
```

Comment: Thank you. however it says  ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined